# Customisation of modern pages

Tags: custom-masterpage, modern-experience, modern-pages, 2019, modern-team-site

I have a SharePoint 2019 site.

I want to customize its home page (modern page) so as to suit a particular user's requirement. I need the hero web part to contain the most frequently visited links of a user and allow the user to drag and drop those links wherever he wants. Is it possible? if yes, please help.

Images are attached for reference:

[image: Customization needed for frequently visited links]
[image: Customization required for drag and drop feature]

Comment: Have you tried using Quick Links web part? Those links will be fixed for all users or it will change for each user?

Comment: Ganesh Sanap, yes i have used quick links. They are usually the same for all users butu I want them to be user specific.

Answer (score 0):

The hero web part does not have that functionality, though the "highlighted content" part does. In the configuration of the highlighted content part, you can set the "type" to page, or perhaps all, or whichever meets your needs. Then, be sure to set the "sort by" property to most viewed or trending. While you can't get the exact look of the hero part, there are a few layout options.

Comment: Hi, we have tried the highlighed content web part but what we want frequently visited links to be shown person wise (different for each user, according to his own frequency of visiting those links)